# Redux combine reducers for complex object

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

I am trying to build an app for university where users can take part in studies. 
Each study is a complex object which contains an array of tasks here is a link of an example object http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d52380055fdc33657a83317a4c23b4a0

Currently i have only 2 reducers. One which does everything like adding and removing studies, and adding and removing tasks from a study and a second reducer to say which study is currently displayed. But i think it would make sense to split the reducers so i have one reducer for the studies and one for the tasks.

I know i can combine reducers in react via

```
combineReducers({
activeStudy,
studies})
```

but as far as i know this only works for objects on the same level and not nested ones. How would i do this for my studies, or would splitting the reducer into multiple reducers even make sense?

Comment: Even list is also an `Object` but you will need to face consequences of object mutability.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has similar problems i finally discovered a solution to my problem. I thought i was limited to combine reducers in the index reducer and did not know that i also could call other reducers from reducers themselves. If anyone has similar problems getting started with redux i can really recommend this video series on egghead https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux